# Javascript for-loop executes code only one time

Tags: javascript

I have a problem that a for-loop executes its code just one time instead of the given number times.

If I put something thats not a number into the textfield I get the Error and console.log() shows me the number I put in the textbox.

It doesnt matter what code it would execute, I tried that aswell.

Code:

```
function Mehrere() {

    var Anzahl = document.getElementById("Anzahl").value;
    var AnzahlInt = parseInt(Anzahl);
    console.log(AnzahlInt);

    if (AnzahlInt > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < AnzahlInt; i++) {
            Kreis();
        }
    } else {
        alert("Error");
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Nope. That loop will definitely run more than once, provided `AnzahlInt` is `> 1`. [Proof](http://jsfiddle.net/8cer4bge/) But it won't if `Kreis` changes `i`.

Comment: What does Kreis() do? Also Please use `for (var i=0...` in case some other loop accesses the now global var `i`

Comment: what is the value returned by console.log(AnzahlInt); ?

Comment: Presented code doesn't match description of problem

Comment: Kreis() creates a circle

Comment: Does it use `i` in there?

Comment: console.log() returns the correct value

Comment: Add _complete_ code, see [mcve]

Comment: What is the value of Anzahllnt? When console. Log it?

Comment: Great find on the duplicate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) because you haven't declared `i`. I'm guessing that the function `Kreis`, which you haven't shown, **also** uses a global `i`. So when you call `Kreis` the first time, you change the value of `i` so it's higher than the loop limit.

Example:

```js
function Mehrere() {

    var Anzahl = document.getElementById("Anzahl").value;
    var AnzahlInt = parseInt(Anzahl);
    console.log(AnzahlInt);

    if (AnzahlInt > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < AnzahlInt; i++) {
            Kreis();
        }
    } else {
        alert("Error");
    }
}
function Kreis() {
  snippet.log("In Kreis, changing i to 20");
  i = 20;
}
Mehrere();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Anzahl" value="10">
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Moral: Declare your variables:

```js
function Mehrere() {
    var i;                   // <==============================

    var Anzahl = document.getElementById("Anzahl").value;
    var AnzahlInt = parseInt(Anzahl);
    console.log(AnzahlInt);

    if (AnzahlInt > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < AnzahlInt; i++) {
            Kreis();
        }
    } else {
        alert("Error");
    }
}
function Kreis() {
  snippet.log("In Kreis, changing i to 20");
  i = 20;
}
Mehrere();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Anzahl" value="10">
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: yep thats it thank you man

Answer (score 0):

Use `let` keyword.
You are using `i` as `global` variable. which might be killing your loop. 
or you can use `var` also. 
[let reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

```
function Mehrere() {

    var Anzahl = document.getElementById("Anzahl").value;
    var AnzahlInt = parseInt(Anzahl);
    console.log(AnzahlInt);

    if (AnzahlInt > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < AnzahlInt; i++) {
            Kreis();
        }
    } else {
        alert("Error");
    }
}
```

Browser compatibility of `let` keyword. 
[image]

Comment: Since all browsers support `let` right? `var` works in ALL browsers

Comment: @mplungjan Yeah i was just adding the compatibility table. Sorry for the delay. :P